# Drupal not showing custom and dynamic hook menu url for sitemap

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, sitemap

I have a Dynamic Hook. www.example.com/institute shows all the institute in the Website. www.example.com/institute/a-demo-institute shows Institute specific page.

```
    $items['institute'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'example_institute_node',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'));
```

But when generating sitemap using sitemap module, this urls are not showing. I tried to use `path_save` to save the url. This happening for every hook in custom module written by me.

Comment: Which site map module are you using? Site Map (https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map ), XMLSitemap (https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) or something else?

Comment: I am currently using https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for you, but may be helpful for others :)

[Sitemap](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_map) module can automatically show only

1. Front page
2. Menus
3. Taxonomy terms

All other pages, including your custom, may be added using `hook_site_map()`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_site_map().
 */
function mymodule_site_map() {

  // Suppose you got $links array above somehow.
  return theme('links', array(
    'links' => $links,
    'attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('site-map-extra')
    ),
  ));
}
```